# MarkLogic 8 transformation in JavaScript

Tags: marklogic

I'm trying to use a JavaScript transform on a JavaScript REST ext. I can't get the transform to be used. To check this, I write a trace log line as seen in the scripts below.
I've had trouble uploading the transform with Roxy so I used a CURL command for the transform. The command is included.

When I call this URL, I expect 'transform running' to show up in my log file:
    http://localhost:12040/v1/resources/somethingext?rs:yes=no&transform=something

All I get is the 'ext running'.

somethingext.sjs:

```
/**
 * @name somethingext 
 * This REST extentsion provides SOAP service for the shipment data
 */

function post(context, params, input) {
    try {
      xdmp.trace('somethingext', 'ext running ');
      // or: xdmp.log('transform');
   }
   catch(err){
   }
}

// Main
exports.POST = post;
```

something-transform.sjs:

```
function something(context, params, content) {
    var mutableDoc = content.toObject();
    xdmp.trace('something', 'transform running');
};

exports.transform = something;
```

CURL used to upload transform:

```
curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -X PUT -i \
    --data-binary @"./something-transform.sjs" \
    -H "Content-type: application/vnd.marklogic-javascript" \
    'http://localhost:12040/LATEST/config/transforms/something'
```

Comment: Did you enable trace events on the Diagnostics page of the Default group? Perhaps better to try xdmp.log first..

Comment: I'll try the log instead of the trace.yes, the ext shows up but the transform does not

Comment: Did you list all used trace event labels?

Comment: Both have the same label in my local code. Maybe this is a clue.. had Roxy issue getting the trasnform over the line. https://github.com/marklogic/roxy/issues/506

Answer (score 2):

I think the main issue here is that you are calling a REST extension, and you cannot apply the transform parameter to that. That only works for /v1/documents, /v1/search, and a few others if I am not mistaken. See also:

http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/resources/[name]

HTH!

Comment: Does not compute. At the previous project we use:  servername:8012/v1/resources/obiproject-ingest?rs:title=main_node&rs:transform=manual-transform or is the transform here just a parameter?

Comment: Yes, hence the rs: prefix in `rs:transform`.. :)

Comment: Thijs - that's a custom extension that uses a transform, and my hunch is that the custom extension currently only supports xqy/xsl transforms.

Comment: Ok, so I need to ingest using the /v1/documents and add my transform to that? Explained here: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/transforms#id_26300

Comment: That can be a useful alternative approach, and elegant as well. But if your extension need to do more than just transform-and-ingest, you could also upload the xsl as a plain xsl in modules, and `xdmp:xslt-invoke` that from within your extension.